# How to use more than one Server Name or IPs(see screenshot) by using variables in jmeter for same Http Request?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

How to use more than one Server Name or IPs(see screenshot) by using variables in jmeter for same Http Request ? better providing example?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a list of domains (hostnames or IP addresses) you can substitute this `awe.bcu.com` hard-coded value with i.e. [__StringFromFile](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__StringFromFile) function pointing to the file containing this list like:

[image: JMeter String From File]

Another option is using [CSV Data Set Config](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733689-Using-CSV-DATA-SET-CONFIG) configured like:

[image: CSV Data Set Config JMeter]

In that case put `${hostname}` into the "Server Name or IP" field.

Comment: if we are using first option  __StringFromFile then what kind of file need to be used? csv,txt...so on? thanks

Comment: any type of text file (non-binary) given each domain name comes on next line